# How to fully Style a marker in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, style, markers

Styling a marker is possible with  pointToLayer I don't know how to get a marker change style for mouse over and for click etc....

```
    var map = L.map('map', {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new L.latLng(35.948782,8.139912),
            layers: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
        });

    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 4,
    fillColor: "black",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};
    var piky1=new L.geoJson(pick1,{
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
        'mousemove': function (e) {
        //I want to make the point a red syle ?
                color: 'red';
                piky1.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name);
       }});}}).addTo(map);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gevzoxs1/49/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setStyle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-setstyle) within the `mousemove` function:

```
layer.on({
    'mousemove': function (e) {
        //I want to make the point a red style ?
        this.setStyle({fillColor:"#f00"});
        ...
    }
});
```